# loop div in inline position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code below to create a loop of div using javascript. It's working fine on looping the div that I wanted. But the problem is the alignment of the `div`. Its in alternate position. What I want to accomplish here is to have my design `div` to be aligned.

**Expected Output**

> First Div | Second Div  <<-- First Loop
>
> First DIv | Second Div <<-- Second Loop

**Current Design in my code**

> | First DIv
>
> First Div |

```js
function isOdd(n) {
  var IsOdd = false;
  if (Math.abs(n % 2) == 1) {
    IsOdd = true;
  }
  return IsOdd;
}


$("#click").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var odd = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
  var even = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
  var counter = 0;
  var FireCounter = [1, 2, 3]
  for (var i = 0; i < FireCounter.length; i++) {
    var ArchPlanDetails = $("#frmPlanDetails").find("div.divHide:visible").find("div#collapse" + FireCounter[i]).find(".req");
    var cardTitle = $("#frmPlanDetails").find("div.divHide:visible").find("div#collapse" + FireCounter[i]).parent().find(".card-title")[0]; //.innerText;
    console.log(cardTitle);
    var dividedAlertPlanDetails = FireCounter.length / 2;
    var mainCard = "";
    mainCard = '<div class="row">' +
      '<div class="col-md-6" id="divBody_' + i + '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="col-md-6" id="divBody2_' + i + '">' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';
    $("#modalAlert .modal-body").append(mainCard);
    var fieldSet = '<fieldset class="border p-2 mt-2">' +
      '<legend style="color:black !important; font-size:30px !important">' + cardTitle + '</legend>' +
      '<div id="fieldDivID' + i + '"></div>' +
      '<fieldset>';
    //var cards = '<div class="card" id="HelloWorld_' + i + '"> <div class="card-header bg-success"><h3 class="card-title">' + cardTitle + ' </h3 ></div> <div class="card-body"> </div>'
    if (isOdd(i)) {
      $("#modalAlert .modal-body #divBody_" + i).append(fieldSet);
    } else {
      $("#modalAlert .modal-body #divBody2_" + i).append(fieldSet);
    }
    counter++;
    $.each(ArchPlanDetails, function(Index, Value) {
      var appendBody = "";
      var id = "#fieldDivID" + i;
      var divID = "#divBody_" + i;
      var divID2 = "#divBody2_" + i;
      var textboxValue = $(Value).find("input[type=text],[type=number]").val();
      var InnerText = Value.innerText.trim();

      appendBody = '<div class="row mt-2" style="font-size:20px">' +
        '<div class="col-md-12"> ' + InnerText + ' </div >' +
        '</div >';

      if (textboxValue == "") {
        if (isOdd(i)) {
          $(divID + " " + id).append(appendBody);
        } else {
          $(divID2 + " " + id).append(appendBody);
        }
      }
    });
  }


  $("#modalAlert .modal-header").html("Header");
  $("#modalAlert").modal("show");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form id="frmPlanDetails">
  <div class="col-md-12 divHide" id="dvFireCounter1">
    <div id="card_one" class="card">
      <div class="card-header bg-success pt-0 pb-0">
        <h3 class="card-title pt-1">
          <span id="FireCounter1"></span> Plan A
          <a class="fa fa-window-minimize float-right FAHide" id="min" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" href="#collapseOne"></a>
          <a class="custom-control custom-checkbox float-right">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="Fire" name="FireIsComplied" value="true">
            <label class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal" for="Fire">
                        Complied
                    </label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
          </a>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="collapse show pt-3 pl-4 pr-4" data-parent="#accordion">
        <fieldset class="border p-2">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 req">
              Ave. Cover(mm)
              <input type="text" class="form-control flat" name="FireAveCover" id="" placeholder="25">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 req">
              Overall Depth(mm)
              <input type="text" class="form-control flat" name="FireOverAll" id="" placeholder="150">
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-md-12 divHide" id="dvFireCounter2">
    <div id="card_one" class="card">
      <div class="card-header bg-success pt-0 pb-0">
        <h3 class="card-title pt-1">
          <span id="FireCounter2"></span> Plan B
          <a class="fa fa-plus float-right FAHide" id="min" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" href="#collapseOne"></a>
          <a class="custom-control custom-checkbox float-right">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="BP" name="BPIsComplied" value="true">
            <label class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal" for="BP">
                        Complied
                    </label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
          </a>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="collapse pt-3 pl-4 pr-4" data-parent="#accordion">
        B
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <div class="col-md-12 divHide" id="dvFireCounter3">
    <div id="card_one" class="card">
      <div class="card-header bg-success pt-0 pb-0">
        <h3 class="card-title pt-1">
          <span id="FireCounter3"></span> Plan C
          <a class="fa fa-plus float-right FAHide" id="min" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse3" href="#collapseOne"></a>
          <a class="custom-control custom-checkbox float-right">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="AS" name="ASIsComplied" value="true">
            <label class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal" for="AS">
                        Complied
                    </label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
          </a>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="collapse pt-3 pl-4 pr-4" data-parent="#accordion">
        C
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="click">Click</button>
</form>



<div class="modal fade" id="modalAlert" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header bg-success">
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
      </div>
      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Modal footer -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75Ln0zrq/)

Comment: Have you tried just giving the formed divs a common class and applying CSS rules to style how you want? Could you provide your CSS?

Comment: @CodeSpent I don't have any CSS it's pure js code.

Comment: Use CSS on your div classes to achieve the layout you want. JS methods would be much more convoluted than needed. I'd recommend some methods, but I don't see the generated divs in your html there. If you can include a sample we can go from there.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here. I'm sure your "expected output" and "current design" are meaningful, but are lost on me at first glance, perhaps you could use photos?  Or be more specific, using "Ave. Cover" and "Overall Depth" as examples